# Most suitable alternative domain suffix for a non-profit if .org is not available

Tags: domains, domain-registration

If .us is best suitable suffix for a US located non-profit organization instead of .org, in a situation that .org and .com are not available? Or .net? or .agency?

or a domain name by adding "the" to it, like:
theorganizationname.org

Comment: It really doesn't matter. Pick what you feel is best.

Comment: @John Conde Actually it does, .us has geo restriction that other org would had to be aware of. So, not what feel the best (completely) :)

Comment: Adam For the future, if you use the at symbol and a name to notify or communicate with someone, remove the spaces. Otherwise, it will not work. It has also been my experience that if a domain you want is taken, just give it a few weeks and you will think of a really awesome domain name or an alternative that you may like better. I know this sounds silly. But it really does seem to work. Sometimes we get mental blocks because we are trying to go in one direction too hard. Good luck with your search.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks for your kind advice hehe, just that for a non-profit it cost $2000 to change our name in official regiseration and it has decided prior our website setup... so yea lol

Comment: I am sure you will find a good solution. I do not have ideas on the TLDs for you. I wish I have something- something brilliant! But this is not my day for brilliant. Hell, I am struggling for mediocre!

Comment: And nobody mentioned the dot-ngo (.ngo) suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your organization is in another country, such as the United Kingdom, then .org.uk would be ideal.

If your organization has a specific purpose that falls into one of the newer generic top-level domains, then choosing a generic name might be better than .org. If you organization is a school, for example, then .academy could be excellent.

There are some little-used TLDs such as .help, .support, and .guide, too.

If you are a cooperative, then .coop is perfect.

[The full list of TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) may be useful to you.

You can always use a domain name that signals your nonprofit status: AwesomeCharity.us or non-profit.OrgName.com (and www.orgname.com would still work).

Comment: hum, .com is not available as well, in my senario. So I suppose choose a .us is better than theOrgName.org? :) Let me know!

Comment: I think appending "the" will contribute to confusion with the other organization. .us at least tells your users where you are located. TBH, I have not researched the requirements for .us, though.